# Getting wrong output for some test cases

Tags: python-3.7

**PART BELOW IS THE PROBLEM STATEMENT:**
We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return True if we are in trouble.

**TEST-CASES:**
parrot_trouble(True, 6) → True
parrot_trouble(True, 7) → False
parrot_trouble(False, 6) → False

**CODE:(I TRIED/WROTE)**

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  if talking and hour<7 or hour>20:
    return True
  if not talking and hour>7 or hour<=20:
    return False
```

**TEST CASES NOT RUNNING:**
parrot_trouble(False, 21) → False, but i am getting True
parrot_trouble(False, 23) → False, but i am getting True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the `if talking and hour<7 or hour>20:` statement.

What you are really saying with this is `if (talking and hour<7) or hour>20`. This means that, if the hour is over 20, this will always return True no matter what.

Try something like this:

```
def parrot_talking(talking, hour):
    if (talking and hour<7) or (talking and hour>20):
        return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: Thank You, for the answer. It really helped me a lot! Your answer also helped me clear my concepts in comparison operators.

Comment: @SoumyadeepChatterjee apologies, I made a logic error. You can actually omit the second if and just use `else: return False`

Comment: No problem! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, remember that `(P and Q) or R` is different than `P and (Q or R)`.  You intended the latter, but Python interpreted it as the first.  In python and several other programming languages, stringing together ands and ors, it will apply these from left to right.  I am of the opinion that parentheses will help keep your thoughts organized and should be used even if leaving them out would mean the same thing.  In your case, forgetting the parentheses caused the error in your code.  When you ran parrot_trouble(False, 21) it returned true since `hour>20` was true.

Second, rather than having a second if statement to return false, it is much cleaner here to either use an else statement or no statement at all.  Even better, don't use an if statement to begin with and instead simplify all of this into a single return statement.  Further, your negation of your if statement was incorrect.  The negation of `talking and (hour<7 or hour>20)` is actually `not talking or (hour >= 7 and hour <= 20)`

```py
   def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
      return (talking and (hour<7 or hour>20))
```

Comment: Thank You! The shortened format is really cool stuff. Thanks for sharing.